# How to handle properly error response to preflighted request in Angular

Tags: angular, cors, preflight, http-response-codes

I want to:

- use "Authorization: Bearer token" header in my angular app, to control access to data served by backend server, and
- display error messages sent by server in angular app, in case user is not authorized to access data.

What I do:

- I send request from angular app (client) to backend server (php).
- Request includes "Authorization: Bearer token" header so it is preflighted.
- When server sends response with 200 response code there is no problem.
- When server sends response with error response code (eg. 401 or 403) Angular client doesn't receive server response, All I see in console is error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/index.php' 
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have checked, that when I use simple request (without "Authorization: Bearer token" header) and server responds with error code, angular client receives full response with error code, like in example below:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2022 23:24:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.11
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization
Content-Length: 47
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

{"code":401,"message":"unauthorised: no token"}
```

Below two cases:

1. angular client code without "Authorization: Bearer token" header - it is working fine

```
  login(login:any){
    console.debug("login",login);
    let params = new HttpParams({fromObject:{"login":login}});
    console.debug("params",params);
    const observable = this.HTTP.post( this.path, params ); // <===== simple request, no problem
    observable.subscribe((response:any)=>{
      console.debug("response",response);
      if(response.code == 200) {
        let token = JSON.parse(response.message);
        this.userToken = token;
        this.loginErrorMessage = "";
      } else {
        this.userToken = "";
        this.loginErrorMessage = "("+response.code+") "+response.message
      }
    })
  }
```

2. angular client code WITH "Authorization: Bearer token" header - here a I have a problem

```
  login(login:any){
    console.debug("login",login);
    let params = new HttpParams({fromObject:{"login":login}});
    console.debug("params",params);
    const observable = this.HTTP.post( this.path, params ,{ headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer " + this.appToken}});
    // const observable = this.HTTP.post( this.path, params ,{ headers: {"MyHeader":"my-header-value"}});
    // const observable = this.HTTP.post( this.path, params );
    observable.subscribe({
      next:(response:any)=>{
        console.debug("response",response);
        if(response.code == 200) {
          let token = JSON.parse(response.message);
          this.userToken = token;
          this.loginErrorMessage = "";
        } else {
          this.userToken = "";
          this.loginErrorMessage = "("+response.code+") "+response.message
        }
      },
      error:(error:any)=>{
        console.debug("error",error);
        this.userToken = "";
        
        this.loginErrorMessage = error.statusText + ": " + error.message;
        // "Http failure response for http://localhost/index.php: 0 Unknown Error"
        // this is response from browser I think, and for sure it is not response from server
        // in addition to that I don't see any response headers in browser developer panel
      }
    })
  }
```

server side (php) headers

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization');
```

Is it possible to use "Authorization: Bearer token" header in Angular client request and read response from server with response code other than 200?

Answer (score 0):

I have a server which authenticates similarly. My request looks a little like this:

```js
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";

//...

const body = {
    "username": form.username,
    "password": form.password
}
this.http.post<any>(
    '/login',
    body, 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({"Authorization": token})}).subscribe({
        next: data => {
            switch (data.status) {
                case 'ok':
                    //Do stuff
                default:
                    //Error
            }
        },
        error: error => {
            //ERROR!
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have edited my code as You did. Now I got some error information but it is not response from  server, it is error response from browser I think. I received: "Http failure response for http://localhost/index.php: 0 Unknown" when server sends {"code":401,"message":"unauthorised: no token"}

Comment: Without seeing your changes, there's not much I can suggest. I would try logging the entire response - and checking that your client is correctly receiving what you expect.

Comment: Problem is I do not receive any response from the server, I got only error message from the browser. The changes in code are shown (example nr 2). I have added error handling:  observable.subscribe({
      next: response=>{ ... }
      error: (error:any)=>{ ...
        // "Http failure response for http://localhost/index.php: 0 Unknown Error"
        // this is response from browser I think, and for sure it is not response from server
        // in addition to that I don't see any response headers in browser developer panel
      }
    })

Comment: OK, did you try using the `new HttpHeaders(<headers>)` on line 12 of my code?

Comment: Yes, it has same effect. Fortunately it's my backend server, so as a work-around I will send error code in response body and always 200 in response header. At least until someone cracks this out :-)

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but for status code, try `error.status` in the `error` block of my answer, and for the actual object returned from your server, try `error.error` in the same block (line 22 of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the error. Right now in the above code, you are only passing in the success handler function. You need to also pass in the error handler function and pass it the error object parameter.

Here is a link you might find useful on this topic. [RxJs Error Handling](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/)

Comment: Thx. I have edited my code as You suggested. Now I got some error information but it is not response from server, it is error response from browser I think. I received: "Http failure response for localhost/index.php: 0 Unknown" when server sends {"code":401,"message":"unauthorised: no token"}